# iOS Charts, wavy lines

Tags: ios, swift3, linechart, ios-charts

Let's get straight to the point: I started to use iOS Charts by Daniel Gindi, but I just can't reproduce this wavy lines in my line chart 
[image]

(and please notice that this image is picked form the repository of iOS charts!)

All I get is just this, simple straight lines with no curves
[image]

And this is the code in viewDidLoad that I used for showing that:

```
    let ys1 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return sin(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141 * 1.5) }
    let ys2 = Array(1..<10).map { x in return cos(Double(x) / 2.0 / 3.141) }

    let yse1 = ys1.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
    let yse2 = ys2.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }

    let data = LineChartData()
    let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "Hello")
    ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
    ds1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    ds1.drawValuesEnabled = false
    data.addDataSet(ds1)

    let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse2, label: "World")
    ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
    ds2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
    ds2.drawValuesEnabled = false
    data.addDataSet(ds2)
    self.viewChart.data = data

    self.viewChart.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white

    self.viewChart.chartDescription?.text = "Linechart Demo"
```

Can someone help me? Thank you!

Comment: Can you add some more detail to your question, please? Some code from your attempt would help a lot.

Comment: Done. thanks for the tip

Comment: Check the graph x and y axis ranges you are setting. Are they not to small for the data you are plotting?

Comment: I doubt the since graph is created using a fixed set of data points, but rather by using some built-in sin functionality.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Please check this :

```
let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse1, label: "Hello")
ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
ds1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
ds1.drawValuesEnabled = false
ds1.mode = .cubicBezier // add this line
data.addDataSet(ds1)

let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(values: yse2, label: "World")
ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
ds2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
ds2.drawValuesEnabled = false
ds2.mode = .cubicBezier // add this line
data.addDataSet(ds2)
```