# plotting sine and cosine with charts have kinks

Tags: ios, swift, charts, ios-charts

I use this changed code from another user to plot sine and cosine [iOS Charts, wavy lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46058012/ios-charts-wavy-lines)

```
import UIKit
import Charts

class ViewController: UIViewController, ChartViewDelegate{

    var lineChartView: LineChartView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {


        lineChartView = LineChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height))
        lineChartView?.delegate = self
        self.view.addSubview(lineChartView!)

        let ys1 = Array(0..<10).map { x in return sin(Double(x)) }
        let ys2 = Array(0..<10).map { x in return cos(Double(x)) }

        let yse1 = ys1.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
        let yse2 = ys2.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }

        let data = LineChartData()
        let ds1 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yse1, label: "Hello")
        ds1.colors = [NSUIColor.red]
        ds1.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        ds1.drawValuesEnabled = false
        ds1.mode = .cubicBezier
        data.addDataSet(ds1)

        let ds2 = LineChartDataSet(entries: yse2, label: "World")
        ds2.colors = [NSUIColor.blue]
        ds2.drawCirclesEnabled = false
        ds2.drawValuesEnabled = false
        ds2.mode = .cubicBezier
        data.addDataSet(ds2)
        self.lineChartView.data = data

        self.viewChart.gridBackgroundColor = NSUIColor.white

        self.lineChartView.chartDescription?.text = "Linechart Demo"
        }
```

But the my graph does not look good, because as you can see the resulting grah has some kinks.

[image]

What can I do to smooth the graph of non-linear functions ? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here:

```
    let ys1 = Array(0..<10).map { x in return sin(Double(x)) }
    let ys2 = Array(0..<10).map { x in return cos(Double(x)) }

    let yse1 = ys1.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
    let yse2 = ys2.enumerated().map { x, y in return ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x), y: y) }
```

You are only using 10 values. It is not that surprising that the curve is not smooth. Even though you are doing `ds1.mode = .cubicBezier`, but the Charts library can only do so much smoothing for you. This line is not a magic spell.

To make the curve more smooth, we can use more values of sin(x) and cos(x) that are closer together. Instead of 10, let's use 100 values from 0 to 10, with a step of 0.1 each time.

```
let ys1 = Array(0..<100).map { x in ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x) / 10, y: sin(Double(x) / 10)) }
let ys2 = Array(0..<100).map { x in ChartDataEntry(x: Double(x) / 10, y: cos(Double(x) / 10)) }
```